# Piping the output of a command, but only if the output is non-empty

Tags: unix, pipe, stdout

Is there a way under Unix that I can run a command and pipe its output to another command, but only if the output is non-empty? Something like

```
command --some-arg | something_magical | mail -s "Don't send this e-mail if it would be empty" foo@bar.com
```

It there something simple I can put in for `something_magical`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can find the answer in this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/210054/make-a-pipe-conditional-on-non-empty-return).

Anyway you can put this function in the magical part:

```
pipe_if_not_empty () {
  head=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null; echo a)
  head=${head%a}
  if [ "x$head" != x"" ]; then
    { printf %s "$head"; cat; } | "$@"
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test a file on being zero or non-zero with

```
if [ -s file ]
```

Check it out using

```
man test
```

Comment: How would I use this to pipe something to another command, but only if that something is non-empty?

Comment: I'm assuming you're not piping, but redirecting to a file. Then you can evaluate the file. It sounds a simple and effective method, although other methods are possible (as often). You can put a command into a variable as well, and check if the variable is empty or not. That's another method, even if you not not need the output in a variable.